# react router - make an ajax call only once per component

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have set my routes as follow:

```
<Router>
    <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
        <Route path="/about" component={About} />
        <Route path="/contact" component={Contact} />
    </Switch>
</Router>
```

On the Home component I want to make an ajax call only the fist time when is mounted.

```
export default class Home extends Component {
    componentDidMount(){
        //make ajax call only once. Do some stuff on .then()
    }
}
```

The problem is that if the users switches the pages between Home and About, the Home compoment will render everything again, therefore my ajax call will be triggered again.

How can I solve this issue?
Should I store the first data fetch on a redux store and then use the if statement or is there a better approach?

Comment: You can cache the data or return a promise. Once promise is resolved, you will have access to data. No IF statement is needed.

Comment: cache where? on the store? localStorage? if you can, please add a sample

Comment: Should I store the first data fetch on a redux store and then use the if statement  ---> if you are using redux, it is best approach.

Comment: @NarasimhaReddy for now, no, I'm not using it, but even so, I will still have to make an IF statement to check if the data was fetched before, right?

Comment: yes, you need to check whether data is there or not in your redux state.

Comment: is this the best way to do? I'm a novice on react/redux so I'd like to use the best practices...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to go for Redux, you need to dispatch an action to fetch the data if it's not there yet.

```
class Home extends Component {
    componentDidMount(){
        if (!this.props.homeContent) {
            this.props.dispatch(fetchHomeContent());
        }
    }
}

// Map redux store to your component props
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
     return {
         'homeContent': state.homeContent
     }
}

// Redux 'connect' function, to subscribe your component for state changes.
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Home);
```

You action is async, so you should use redux-thunk middleware, please check out the doc for it's setup.

Your actions:

```
function fetchHomeContent(subreddit) {
     return dispatch => {
         return fetch(`https://your-domain/pathname`)
             .then(response => response.json())
             .then(json => dispatch(receiveData(json)))
     }
}

function receiveData(json) {
    return {
        type: 'receive',
        data
    }
}
```

And your reducer:

```
switch (action.type) {
    case 'receive':        
        return Object.assign({}, state, {
            'homeContent': action.data
        })
    default:
        return state
}
```

This is just to give your an idea of your general setup, but you still need to wire it (setup your store, root reducer and etc), the best way is to follow Redux [docs/tutorial](http://redux.js.org/).

This solution would be good if you need similar caching for other parts of your app. In case it's a big overhead for you, you can save in localStorage, like you mentioned above. And read it on componentDidMount.

Comment: yes,this is a sufficient sample for me. Anyway, what I was curios more about was if I still need to use an IF statement, so I will.